# How to enter one splash screen into either one of two activities condtionally

Tags: java, android, authentication, screen, splash-screen

I creating a quiz app

First activity has a google sign in activity and second activity has profile name and place Textfeilds.

In Second Activity has a submit button. After authentication and filling name and place ,when clicking submit button, opens next activity (Third Activity) HomeActivity.

If once a user signed in and profile builded then entered to HomeActivity,
When that user  reopening the app,  does not seen
authentication and profile building activity (First and Second activity).
i.e he directly enters to the HomeActivity. I am builded till here.

The problem is some seconds taking for fetching data from firebase for checking the user is already signed or not.

I want to make a splash screen that shows till loading my HomeActivity(i.e Third Activity). If user not signed in splash screen shows till loading
first activity.

Till now not created a splash screen activity.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you probably _don't_ want a splash screen, unless you want to flash content to users, there's no guarantee how long this call will take, it could be done very quickly, or it could take very long, it will depend. just show a loading indicator instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.